# A simple typing game using JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I'm new to JavaFX and I'm trying to make a game with it.

It is just a simple typing game .

I want to set some characters or words or string objects that are falling in from the top of the screen to the bottom. The user will have to type this character, word or string before it will have fallen down to the bottom of the screen.

I have no idea how to make a game, and this is first time I want to make a game.

Now, I would like to know whether my thoughts on this topic are right, and if there is a more elegant way to achieve my goal.

I hope you can give me some advice!

Comment: In my opinion you should do something simpler like [a game where you literally spend money to make money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_game). Also, please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) out.

Comment: sorry i'm not understand what the following steps i want to follow . please help

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. As it stands, your question is far too broad for this forum, which is for specific programming questions. You should try something and post code with specific questions about it if you get stuck.

Comment: tnx a lot but please give me some link so that i can work through it.